# Google Glass Crashes when trying to boot compiled zImage from glass-omap-xrr02 branch

Tags: linux-kernel, google-glass

I am trying to make some changes in the glass kernel and am following the steps in https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/system. But even when I am compiling the base kernel code from google's repository (glass-omap-xrr02 branch) and trying to boot with the zImage, the device crashes after showing a screen with the text "GLASS".
I am using the factory system images from XE20.1
Do I need to work with any other branch on XE20.1? Or do I need to make some configuration changes to the defconfig (notle_defconfig)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xrr02 is not the latest (the docs have not been updated) xrw45c is the latest

SO, XE22 corresponds to the latest available kernel, xrx13b so replace xrr02 with xrx13b.

I've confirmed that this one compiles

Comment: Thanks. But I actually tried with xrw45c before (using notle_defconfig). It is giving some error while compiling. That's why I was wondering whether there is a stable version.

Comment: The error was due to some bugs in /drivers/usb/gadget/f_fs.c
If I turn off CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y in the defconfig, the compilation works fine. I think, there are also some patches for f_fs.c

https://gitorious.org/replicant/kernel_goldelico_gta04/commit/4608fb7f41568dbd2c1e393098eb0780f1e2fbd1?format=patch

Comment: Extremely long shot, but do you remember if you found a branch which worked? I'm trying to find a working one now too.